# Easeus - Restoring bootable drive issue

Tags: images, restore

I 'm trying to restore my bootable Windows 11 drive which is already backed up to an external hard drive as pbd file format with the EaseUS backup software, and unfortunately, I cannot. While using the EaseUS Todo Backup 2022 through a bootable media flash drive, I can select the pbd image file but on the next step the bootable C drive is simply absent from the list.

My boot drive is an SSD NVME Firecude if that matters.

Thank you.

Comment: Did the SSD go defective?   See if Firecude has a bootable USB test diagnostic.

Comment: No, the SSD is totally fine. I could do a fresh window 11 installation.

Comment: Use a Microsoft Windows 11 USB made from the ISO download and install that.  See if it works.

Comment: Nor sure I follow but I did already a clean Windows 11 installation through a Win 11 bootable USB stick. However, this is not what I want.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that something happened to the backup you made.

Comment: Are you booting from an EaseUS Bootable USB? ([link](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-guide/winpe-bootable-disk.html)) (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I am using EaseUS Todo Backup 2022 bootable media. With this software I cannot see my SSD to restore my image. I also tried the link you provided and made a bootable disk but unfortunately it does not work; I get an error message about a file missing and I am not able to do anything further.

Comment: (1) Is the disk detected in the BIOS? (If not, verify connectors) (2) Do you see in the BIOS an Advanced option that looks similar to "M.2_2 PCIE Storage RAID Support" that is not Enabled? (Enable if found)

Comment: When you made the backup, was there a choice of **file** backup, i.e., backing up your personal data and chosen folders, or making a **full disk image** that backs up **everything**, including the operating system and boot records, as well as your personal files?

Comment: @harrymc, 1) the drive is detected by the bios and as wrote above I was able to reinstall windows. 2) I was not able to find a setting like that. I have an ASUS B660-F M/B or something like that.  The NVME SSD drive is detected by the bios; I can see it in the list in the front page while entering the bios. I have the feeling there is something that makes the drive hidden as some kind of protection measure?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I did a full back up of entire drive. As far as I have understood, the image created copies also of all partitions of the boot drive (SSD).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to solve the issue. The problem was that I had not included the Intel® Rapid Storage Technology Driver during the creation of the bootable medium. Therefore the disk was not available. I recreated the bootable medium with the drivers and voila! Was able to have the pc up and runing in 30 min.

Funny that I knew and doing this when performing fresh windows install but never thought it for the recovery disk.